# size and vertical center navbar items relative to logo image

Tags: css

I am trying to size a navbar logo on the left side of the horizontal navbar and then have the rest of the navbar items take the same vertical space and be vertically centered in the space.  The navbar items currently do not use the full vertical space.  Every sizing attribute that I've tried has created another problem.  Thanks for all help.

Note:  Can't use bootstrap.  Wish I could.

```css
/****************************************/
/* Fixed top navbar with dropdowns      */
/****************************************/
.m-navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

/*.m-navbar li {
    float: left;
}*/

.m-navbar-right {
 float: right;
}
.m-navbar-left {
 float: left;
}

.m-navbar li a, .m-menu-form {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif; 
}

.m-navbar li a:hover:not(.active), .m-dropdown:hover, .m-menu-form:hover {
    /*background-color: #ddd;*/
    background-color: #9dd0f0;
}

.m-navbar-logo-img {
 padding: 3px 0px 4px 4px;
 width: auto;
 max-height: 33px;
 position: relative;
}

.m-navbar li a.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #00719c;
}

.m-navbar li.m-dropdown {
 display: inline-block;
}

.m-dropdown-content {
 display: none;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">
 <title>Navbar Problem</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="m-outer">
  <div class="m-fixed-header">
  <div class="m-navbar">
      <ul>
     <li class="m-navbar-left"><a href="#"><img class="m-navbar-logo-img" src="bugicon.png"></img></a></li>
     <li class="m-navbar-left">
      <form name="idForm" method="post" action="">
          <input type="submit" name="action" class="m-menu-form" value="Home">
      </form>
        </li>
     <li class="m-dropdown m-navbar-left">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="m-dropbtn">Menu 1</a>
      <div class="m-dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Drop 1</a><br>
       <a href="#">Drop 2</a><br>
       <a href="#">Drop 3</a><br>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="m-dropdown m-navbar-left">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="m-dropbtn">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="m-dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Drop 1</a><br>
       <a href="#">Drop 2</a><br>
       <a href="#">Drop 3</a><br>
       <a href="#">Drop 4</a><br>
      <a href="#">Drop 5</a><br>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="m-navbar-right"><a href='#'>Logoff&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try it with display:flex;

```css
/****************************************/
/* Fixed top navbar with dropdowns      */
/****************************************/
.m-navbar ul {
   list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

/*.m-navbar li {
    float: left;
}*/

.m-navbar-right {
 float: right;
}
.m-navbar-left {
 float: left;
}

.m-navbar li a, .m-menu-form {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif; 
}

.m-navbar li a:hover:not(.active), .m-dropdown:hover, .m-menu-form:hover {
    /*background-color: #ddd;*/
    background-color: #9dd0f0;
}

.m-navbar-logo-img {
 padding: 3px 0px 4px 4px;
 width: auto;
 max-height: 33px;
 position: relative;
}

.m-navbar li a.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #00719c;
}

.m-navbar li.m-dropdown {
 display: inline-block;
}

.m-dropdown-content {
 display: none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">
 <title>Navbar Problem</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="m-outer">
  <div class="m-fixed-header">
  <div class="m-navbar">
      <ul>
     <li class="m-navbar-left"><a href="#"><img class="m-navbar-logo-img" src="bugicon.png"></img></a></li>
     <li class="m-navbar-left">
      <form name="idForm" method="post" action="">
          <input type="submit" name="action" class="m-menu-form" value="Home">
      </form>
        </li>
     <li class="m-dropdown m-navbar-left">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="m-dropbtn">Menu 1</a>
      <div class="m-dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Drop 1</a><br>
       <a href="#">Drop 2</a><br>
       <a href="#">Drop 3</a><br>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="m-dropdown m-navbar-left">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="m-dropbtn">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="m-dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Drop 1</a><br>
       <a href="#">Drop 2</a><br>
       <a href="#">Drop 3</a><br>
       <a href="#">Drop 4</a><br>
      <a href="#">Drop 5</a><br>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="m-navbar-right"><a href='#'>Logoff&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Flex!  That gets the vertical alignment sorted out. I did not add the justify-content.  Removed my m-navbar-left style and replaced the m-navbar-right style with "margin-left: auto".  100% solution.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.